# Worksheet_Change event and shared workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, onchange

Whilst building a project that is intended to be a shared workbook (please don't groan too loudly) I have noticed something rather odd with the Worksheet_change event in relation to the target address.

to highlight this point create a new workbook and add the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
MsgBox (Target.Address(0, 0))
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

When the event is triggered by adding data into a fresh row and the workbook is not shared displays a message box with the relevant cell address as expected.  However, When the workbook is shared and the same process is followed the event fires twice.

Pass 1 returns a message box that displays the address that equates to being the equivalent of

```
 Target.row:Target.row
```

Pass 2 returns the expected cell address.

Incidentally this first pass result is probably why people experience the

> run-time error 13 - Type Mismatch

Whilst this can be overcome by using the following code (or similar) I was wondering if anyone knows why Pass 1 happens at all?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False        
    If Target.Address(0, 0) <> Target.Row & ":" & Target.Row Then
        MsgBox (Target.Address(0, 0))
    End If    
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your work-around works, I'd just go with it and look forward to a host of other problems. Your first sentence hints at the "solution" - don't use shared workbooks. In fact, given the long list of issues with them, MS is moving to deprecate them in favor of "co-authored" workbooks.